# Laravel 8: How to Create and Update with The Same Form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, crud

I have a form in my dashboard where I have a field called "business_name" that is created to its own DB table. The other fields (i.e. first name, last name) are pulled in from the registration. I need to be able to create the "business_name" field and also update that field and those other fields too.

**dashboard_business.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('dashboard_business') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="font-bold" for="businessName">Business Name</label>
        <input class="border border-brand-black border-opacity-20 w-full p-3 rounded-lg mt-2" type="text" name="business_name" id="businessName" value="{{ old('business_name') }}">
        @error('business_name')
            <div class="text-brand-red mt-2 text-base">
                {{ $message }} 
            </div>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="font-bold" for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input class="border border-brand-black border-opacity-20 w-full p-3 rounded-lg mt-2" type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName" value="{{ Auth::user()->first_name }}">
        @error('first_name')
            <div class="text-brand-red mt-2 text-base">
                {{ $message }} 
            </div>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="font-bold" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input class="border border-brand-black border-opacity-20 w-full p-3 rounded-lg mt-2" type="text" name="last_name" id="lastName" value="{{ Auth::user()->last_name }}">
        @error('last_name')
            <div class="text-brand-red mt-2 text-base">
                {{ $message }} 
            </div>
        @enderror
    </div>
</form>
```

**2021_11_24_184250_create_business_dashboards_table.php**

```
 Schema::create('business_dashboards', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unique(['user_id']);
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('business_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('account_type');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is what I have so far in the controller.
**BusinessDashboardController.php**

```
public function index()
{         
    return view('auth.dashboard_business');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'business_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    $request->user()->businessdetails()->create([
        'business_name' => $request->business_name,
    ]);
}
```

How do I do all this on the same form?

Comment: you have the user so just update the user with the other 2 fields ... Models have an `update` method

Answer (score 0):

You can use `updateOrCreate()` method.

```
$reqeust->user()->businessdetails()->updateOrCreate([
     'business_name' => $request->business_name,
]);
```

Also you can write it like that, above method is just refactor of this code:

```
if ($request->user()->businessdetails()->business_name !== null ) {
    $request->user()->businessdetails()->update([
        'business_name' => $request->business_name
    ]);
} else {
   $request->user()->businessdetails()->create([
        'business_name' => $request->business_name
    ]);
}
```

Also, you can read as well this article, I guess it will help you a lot, it's so clear explanations.
https://laravel-news.com/firstornew-firstorcreate-firstor-updateorcreate

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I tried this and its creating multiple records and not overriding the current one.

Comment: I don`t know you read the article which one I mentioned or not. 

also, you can use it like this: 
if ($request->user()->businessdetails()->business_name !== null ) {
    $request->user()->businessdetails()->update([
        'business_name' => $request->business_name
    ]);
} else {
   $request->user()->businessdetails()->create([
        'business_name' => $request->business_name
    ]);
}